# Load articles from X using nodeJS to an existing x.html

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Yah, just another NodeJS noob here. I have googled to try to find answers but since nodeJS is not as popular as php yet so it's not that easy.

Let's say I have an index.html file like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="title">Articles</div>
    <div id="articles">
        <!--Load information from nodeJS-->
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And I have a nodeJS file like this:

```
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    response.write("<div class='articletitle'>ABC</div>");
    response.write("<div class='articletext'>This is a test article</div>");
    response.end();
});

server.listen(3000);
```

What do I want?

- I want to get article from nodeJS output and put it into `#articles`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need a template engine for that. A simple one is EJS (which is very close of what you know in PHP) and here's the exemple (don't forget to install it with *npm*):

```
var http = require('http');
var ejs = require('ejs');

// create http server
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/html'});

  // data to render
  var articles = [{title: 'Hello'}];

  // rendering the ejs file
  ejs.renderFile(__dirname + '/views/articles.ejs',
    {articles: articles},
    function(err, result) {
      // render on success
      if (!err) {
        res.end(result);
      } else {
        res.end('An error occurred');
        console.log(err);
      }
    }
  );
}).listen(3000);

// views/articles.ejs
<html>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="title">Articles</div>
    <div id="articles">
        <% articles.forEach(function(article) { %>
          <h2><%= article.title %></h2>
        <% }); %>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: One more mini-question* So do I need to link nodeJS to domain.com and not index.html file?

Comment: I don't get what you mean.

Comment: Tell if I'm right or not about nodeJS: "Basicly nodejs is a complier that compiles code into a response and sends it to a user"

Comment: It's not a compiler, it's [interpreted language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreted_language) since you need to have NodeJS installed on the computer that will run your code. In your case, you use NodeJS in web case but you could more than that.

Comment: Okay got it! Thanks for your help

Comment: You welcome! Not easy to find some examples in NodeJS when you don't want to use library such as Express.

Comment: No no no, I use express. I'm just kinda new to NodeJS I don't know a lot yet. Well I know a lot more now compared when I asked this question. And I think you shouldn't avoid express. Express is a really good lib that makes your life easier

Comment: I agree: I used it a lot. I was saying that only because of your question

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a template engine like haml or jade.

- http://jade-lang.com/
- http://haml.info/

Also I would recommend to use expressjs.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, since you're new to NodeJS, I strongly recommend you to use the [ExpressJS framework](http://expressjs.com/).
It encapsulates most of the commonly NodeJS needed features.

The best way to easily achieve what you want, is by using some [Template Engine](http://expressjs.com/guide/using-template-engines.html).

For example, you could be using [Jade](http://jade-lang.com/) and your code would be something like this:

```
html
  body
    div#container
      div#title Articles
        div#articles
          each article in articles
            div.articletitle= article.title
            div.articletext= article.text
```

And then, your NodeJS (with the ExpressJS framework) code would be something like:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  var tmpl = {
    articles: [
      { title: 'ABC', text: 'This is a test article' },
      { title: 'XYZ', text: 'Just another random article' }
    ]
  };
  res.render('index', tmpl);
});
```

Comment: Your example is wrong since it use Express syntax. The question doesn't.

Comment: @Swatto updated the answer. Thanks for notifying me!